# Get the absolute file location of a file using nodejs/electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

How can I get the absolute location of a file using file chooser without uploading the file. My main goal is to stream user-selected media files in electron app.

Comment: Consider using the path module? https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use built-in `dialog.showOpenDialog` method:

```js
// For Electron 12 and later
// Install '@electron/remote' module
// const electronRemote = require('@electron/remote')

// For Electron <12
const electronRemote = require('electron').remote

const currentWindow = electronRemote.getCurrentWindow()
const options = { 
  properties: ['openFile'] 
}
electronRemote.dialog.showOpenDialog(currentWindow, options)
  .then(result => {
    const filePath = result.filePaths[0]
    console.log(filePath)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
  })
```